# ifelse with list of possible string matches and no else

Tags: r, if-statement

So normally, if I want to populate a new column data$new.col with 1s if it finds the strings "foo" or "bar" in data$strings and 0s if not, I would use something like this:

```
data$new.col <- ifelse(grepl("foo|bar",
  data$strings, ignore.case = T, perl = T), "1", "0")
```

However, I want to do the equivalent of this without an "else". I tried using a simple assignment but I must be doing something wrong because it's not working:

```
data$new.col[data$strings == "foo|bar"] <- "1"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `data$new.col[data$strings %in% c("foo", "bar")] <- "1"`

***Why your code doesn't work:***

Using the condition `data$strings == "foo|bar"`, you are matching with the (unique) string `"foo|bar"`, not with `"foo"` or `"bar"`. The `%in%` operator allows you to match with any element in the vector `c("foo", "bar")`

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: How would I apply ignore.case to the elements in the c() vector?

Comment: You mean something like this: `vec <- c("FOO", "bar", "foo")`; `grep("foo", vec, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the filter condition as follows:

```
data$new.col[data$strings == "foo" | data$strings == "bar"] <- "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or try

```
data$new.col <- as.integer(grepl("foo|bar",
                                  data$strings,
                                  ignore.case = T,
                                  perl = T))
```

As `grepl` returns a logical vector all you need to do is convert it to numbers. Wrap that expression in `as.character` if you want strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly a one-liner using the tidyverse package:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mpg)
df <-
  mpg %>% 
  select(manufacturer, displ) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = if_else(str_detect(manufacturer, "audi|chev"), 1, 0))
```

The if_else command is a vectorized operation that avoids the need for subsetting.

Comment: How does your answer address OP's requirements? 'I want to do the equivalent of this without an "else" '.